# Reverse a Linked List in place

Tags: javascript, beginner, linked-list

I am solving some programming challenges for learning Javascript. The challenge I chose is:

> Given the head of a singly linked list, reverse it in-place.

Here is my implementation in JS

```
// Given the head of a singly linked list, reverse it in-place.
const ReverseLinkedList = {
    reverseLinkedList: (/** @type{ListNode} */ head) => {
        if (head === undefined) {
            return undefined;
        }

        if (head.next === undefined) {
            return head;
        }

        let temp = head;
        let tail = head.next.next;

        head = temp.next;
        head.next = temp;
        head.next.next = undefined;

        while (tail !== undefined) {
            let tempNext = tail.next;

            temp = head;
            head = tail;
            head.next = temp;

            tail = tempNext;
        }

        return head;
    },
    ListNode: function ListNode(/** @type{ListNode} */ next, val) {
        return {
            next: next,
            val: val
        }
    }
};

module.exports = ReverseLinkedList;
```

and my test class

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const reverseLinkedList = require('../../src/reverseLinkedList');

let head;
let node_01;
let node_02;
let reversed;

node_02 = reverseLinkedList.ListNode(undefined, 2);
node_01 = reverseLinkedList.ListNode(node_02, 1);
head = reverseLinkedList.ListNode(node_01, 0);

reversed = reverseLinkedList.reverseLinkedList(head);
expect(reversed.val).to.equal(2);
expect(reversed.next.val).to.equal(1);
expect(reversed.next.next.val).to.equal(0);
expect(reversed.next.next.next).to.equal(undefined);

node_01 = reverseLinkedList.ListNode(undefined, 1);
head = reverseLinkedList.ListNode(node_01, 0);
head.next = node_01;

reversed = reverseLinkedList.reverseLinkedList(head);
expect(reversed.val).to.equal(1);
expect(reversed.next.val).to.equal(0);
expect(reversed.next.next).to.equal(undefined);

head = reverseLinkedList.ListNode(undefined, 0);
reversed = reverseLinkedList.reverseLinkedList(head);
expect(reversed.val).to.equal(0);
expect(reversed.next).to.equal(undefined);
```

Being a Javascript newbie, any comments on the styling and best practices? Also any comments on the algorithm itself is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of your type-hinting comments.  Let JavaScript be JavaScript.  If you want typing, practice TypeScript instead.

I find it counterintuitive that the `ListNode` constructor takes its `next` parameter before its `val` parameter.  Putting `val` first is more natural (see my `piDigits` example below), and also allows `next` to be omitted for the last node in a list.

You can use the `{val, next}` syntactic shorthand.

As for the `reverseLinkedList` algorithm, there is too much code, with too many special cases.  The fact that you mention `.next.next`, reaching *two* elements ahead, is a sign that you aren't thinking about the loop invariant the right way.  You want the code to consider just the local situation at the `head`.

It's not really appropriate to explicitly set a variable to `undefined`; [`undefined` is supposed to represent the fact that no assignment has taken place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076944/1157100).  In any case, you should be more lenient than checking for `… === undefined`.

I find that it's nearly always unhelpful to use `temp` as a variable name or in a variable name.

```js
const ListNode = (val, next) => { return {val, next}; };

const reverseLinkedList = (head) => {
    let newTail = null;
    while (head) {
        let next = head.next;
        head.next = newTail;
        newTail = head;
        head = next;
    }
    return newTail;
};



let piDigits = ListNode(3, ListNode(1, ListNode(4, ListNode(1, ListNode(5)))));
console.log(reverseLinkedList(piDigits));

let emptyList = null;
console.log(reverseLinkedList(emptyList));
```

Comment: Thank you very much, very clean and helpful. (Even makes me feel embarrassed to be honest.)